# how to send a variable from PHP to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, global, public

The Idea is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var supervar = 'u can reach me anywhere on the page';
</script>

[...some PHP and HTML...]

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#output').html(supervar);
</script>
```

so basicly i need it because I use php includes and need to send the exact location of my PHP file to jQ.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the exact location of my PHP file"? Do you need the file path on the server, i.e. `/var/www/your-app/your-file.php` or a URI, like `yoursite.com/your-app/your-file.php`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to pass data from PHP to JavaScript for my particular case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136997/best-way-to-pass-data-from-php-to-javascript-for-my-particular-case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `supervar` variable is already in scope inside jQuery, because it is declared above the jQuery script. The question is how to assign a variable from PHP and pass it over to `supervar`. Inside your `.php` file, you can simply escape into php when needed within the `<script>` element.

For example, if you want to assign is the public path of your PHP script, you can do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var supervar = <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>;
</script>
```

Your server will execute the php script before serving the following output to the client:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var supervar = '/your-app/your-file.php';
</script>
```