# List files in a directory with PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm trying to write a simple script that's main purpose is to list all files from a directory on the server and save it as an array. Later the client-side script would make some operations like "extracting" the file extension, name and so on.

Right now I'm stuck with a small problem. That is, the script indeed does list all the files from specified directory, but returned data is quite impossible to read by JavaScript.

```
let data = <?php 
  if ($handle = opendir('./share')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
      if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
        echo "$entry ";
      }
    }
    closedir($handle);
  }
?>;
```

And the returned data looks like this:

```
some_image.png other_text.txt meme.gif
```

As probably everybody knows, JavaScript will freak out if we use it anywhere... 
Is there any way I can convert this piece of data to an actual array like the one below?

```
['some_image.png','other_text.txt','meme.gif']
```

Comment: Don't echo the entry but add it to an array? Or [glob()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) and [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)?

Comment: I'm quite new to PHP, could you please make a small example? I never was able to understand anything from php.net. I always looked outside this website.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't. I've tried most of them and was left with a bunch of errors. Also my script needs to be able to handle a variable number of files in that directory, with *any* extension.

Comment: No way - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9137112/754119) should work without a problem. If not, we need to see what error are you getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending your code: write the file entries to an array instead of `echo` ing them right away. Then `json_encode` that array and finally `echo` it in your `<script>` tag

```
<?php
$files = array();
if ($handle = opendir('./share')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            $files[] = $entry;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
$json = json_encode($files);
// var_dump($json);
?>
<script>
let data = <?php echo $json ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: No problem, glad it works

Comment: Since Windows decided to insist on spamming my network with packets when sharing any files, I decided to simply use my Raspberry PI to make a local HTTP/FTP server, and make just make a simple HTML interface to browse the files.